# How to install wxPython on Mac OS 10.8 using MacPorts?

Tags: macos, installation, wxpython, macports

I would like to install wxPython on Mac OS 10.8 using MacPorts. So for I have run into errors. Using pip didn't work because of errors. There are a lot of packages in MacPorts that are related to wxPython. The trick is finding one that works on my version of Mac OS. Hopefully someone knows the right formula.

Answer (score 1):

You've already found that there are several wxPython-related ports in MacPorts:

```
$ port echo name:wxp
py-wxpython-3.0
py-wxpython-4.0
py27-wxpython-3.0
py27-wxpython-4.0
py35-wxpython-4.0
py36-wxpython-4.0
py37-wxpython-4.0
py38-wxpython-4.0
py39-wxpython-4.0
wxPython-3.0
```

Looks like if you want wxPython 3, your only option is to `sudo port install py27-wxpython-3.0` which is for Python 2.7. If you want wxPython 4, you can pick which version of Python 2.7 or 3.x you want.

OS X 10.8 is very old, so there is a possibility that these or any other ports in MacPorts will not work on it. You can look up ports in the [ports web site](https://ports.macports.org) and check to see if they built successfully on the automated build system.

For example, as of this writing, [py39-wxpython-4.0 built successfully on OS X 10.11 and later](https://ports.macports.org/port/py39-wxpython-4.0/details/) but not on 10.10 or earlier. That information could be outdated. You can always try installing the port yourself to see what happens. If you encounter a build failure, please [report it to MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/newticket) so that it can hopefully be fixed.